# problem with jscrollpane in java

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I add a jtextarea to my jscrollpane but I dont know why it's not working!
would u please help me?

problem is my text go down, but scroll not working in GUI.

**I upload all of the code because it easy for u to run it, just create a main file & set size it. u can track problem for these Jscrollpane : jScrollPane1 ,jScrollPane16 jScrollPane4**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import com.borland.jbcl.layout.*;

public class Frame1 extends JFrame {
        JPanel contentPane;
        BorderLayout borderLayout1 = new BorderLayout();
        JMenuBar jMenuBar1 = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu jMenuFile = new JMenu();
        JMenuItem jMenuFileExit = new JMenuItem();
        JMenu jMenuHelp = new JMenu();
        JMenuItem jMenuHelpAbout = new JMenuItem();
        JToolBar jToolBar = new JToolBar();
        JButton jButton1 = new JButton();
        JButton jButton2 = new JButton();
        JButton jButton3 = new JButton();
        ImageIcon image1 = new ImageIcon(masterproject.Frame1.class.getResource(
                "openFile.png"));
        ImageIcon image2 = new ImageIcon(masterproject.Frame1.class.getResource(
                "closeFile.png"));
        ImageIcon image3 = new ImageIcon(masterproject.Frame1.class.getResource(
                "help.png"));
        JLabel statusBar = new JLabel();
        JSplitPane jSplitPane1 = new JSplitPane();
        JPanel jPanel1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel jPanel2 = new JPanel();
        DynamicTree jtProjectList = new DynamicTree();
        BorderLayout borderLayout2 = new BorderLayout();
        JToolBar jToolBar1 = new JToolBar();
        JToolBar jToolBar2 = new JToolBar();
        JButton jbAdd = new JButton();
        JButton jbRemove = new JButton();
        int newNodeSuffix = 0;
        JToolBar jToolBar3 = new JToolBar();
        BorderLayout borderLayout3 = new BorderLayout();
        JPanel jpCore = new JPanel();
        JPanel jpExclusion = new JPanel();
        JLabel jLabel1 = new JLabel();
        JTextArea jTextArea1 = new JTextArea();
        BorderLayout borderLayout4 = new BorderLayout();
        JTable jTable1 = new JTable();
        JPanel jpScope = new JPanel();
        JLabel jLabel2 = new JLabel();
        JTextArea jTextArea2 = new JTextArea();
        JTable jTable2 = new JTable();
        BorderLayout borderLayout5 = new BorderLayout();
        VerticalFlowLayout verticalFlowLayout1 = new VerticalFlowLayout();
        JPanel jpDeliverable = new JPanel();
        JTable jTable3 = new JTable();
        JLabel jLabel3 = new JLabel();
        JTextArea jTextArea3 = new JTextArea();
        BorderLayout borderLayout6 = new BorderLayout();
        JPanel jpAcceptance = new JPanel();
        JPanel jpConstraints = new JPanel();
        JPanel jpAssumption = new JPanel();
        JPanel jpRisk = new JPanel();
        BorderLayout borderLayout7 = new BorderLayout();
        BorderLayout borderLayout8 = new BorderLayout();
        BorderLayout borderLayout9 = new BorderLayout();
        JTable jTable4 = new JTable();
        JTable jTable5 = new JTable();
        JTable jTable6 = new JTable();
        JLabel jLabel4 = new JLabel();
        JLabel jLabel5 = new JLabel();
        JLabel jLabel6 = new JLabel();
        JTextArea jTextArea4 = new JTextArea();
        JTextArea jTextArea5 = new JTextArea();
        JTextArea jTextArea6 = new JTextArea();
        JLabel jLabel7 = new JLabel();
        JTextArea jTextArea7 = new JTextArea();
        JTable jTable7 = new JTable();
        BorderLayout borderLayout10 = new BorderLayout();
        JScrollPane jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane();
        JScrollPane jScrollPane2 = new JScrollPane();
        JScrollPane jScrollPane3 = new JScrollPane();
        JScrollPane jScrollPane4 = new JScrollPane();
        JScrollPane jScrollPane5 = new JScrollPane();
        JScrollPane jScrollPane6 = new JScrollPane();
        JScrollPane jScrollPane7 = new JScrollPane();
        JScrollPane jScrollPane8 = new JScrollPane();
        JScrollPane jScrollPane9 = new JScrollPane();
        JScrollPane jScrollPane10 = new JScrollPane();
        JScrollPane jScrollPane11 = new JScrollPane();
        JScrollPane jScrollPane12 = new JScrollPane();
        JScrollPane jScrollPane13 = new JScrollPane();
        JScrollPane jScrollPane14 = new JScrollPane();
        JScrollPane jScrollPane15 = new JScrollPane();
        JScrollPane jScrollPane16 = new JScrollPane();
        public Frame1() {
            try {
                setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                jbInit();
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Component initialization.
         *
         * @throws java.lang.Exception
         */
        private void jbInit() throws Exception {
            contentPane = (JPanel) getContentPane();
            contentPane.setLayout(borderLayout1);
            this.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
            setSize(new Dimension(753, 483));
            setTitle("Master Project");
            statusBar.setText(" ");
            jMenuFile.setText("File");
            jMenuFileExit.setText("Exit");
            jMenuFileExit.addActionListener(new Frame1_jMenuFileExit_ActionAdapter(this));
            jMenuHelp.setText("Help");
            jMenuHelpAbout.setText("About");
            jMenuHelpAbout.addActionListener(new
                                             Frame1_jMenuHelpAbout_ActionAdapter(this));
            jPanel1.setLayout(borderLayout2);
            jbAdd.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(51, 25));
            jbAdd.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(51, 25));
            jbAdd.setText("Add");
            jbAdd.addActionListener(new Frame1_jbAdd_actionAdapter(this));
            jbRemove.setText("Remove");
            jbRemove.addActionListener(new Frame1_jbRemove_actionAdapter(this));
            contentPane.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 600));
            contentPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 600));
            jSplitPane1.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 55));
            jSplitPane1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 355));
            jSplitPane1.setLastDividerLocation(300);
            jtProjectList.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 324));
            jPanel2.setLayout(borderLayout3);
            jLabel1.setText("Exclusion :");
            jTextArea1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(280, 60));
            jTextArea1.setText("jTextArea1");
            jTextArea1.setLineWrap(true);
            jpExclusion.setLayout(borderLayout4);
            jLabel2.setText("Scope :");
            jTextArea2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(280, 60));
            jTextArea2.setText("jTextArea1");
            jTextArea2.setLineWrap(true);
            jpScope.setLayout(borderLayout5);
            jpCore.setLayout(verticalFlowLayout1);
            jLabel3.setText("Deliverable :");
            jTextArea3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(280, 60));
            jTextArea3.setText("jTextArea3");
            jTextArea3.setLineWrap(true);
            jpDeliverable.setLayout(borderLayout6);
            jpAssumption.setLayout(borderLayout7);
            jpConstraints.setLayout(borderLayout8);
            jpAcceptance.setLayout(borderLayout9);
            jLabel4.setText("Assumption :");
            jLabel5.setText("Constraints :");
            jLabel6.setText("Acceptance :");
            jTextArea4.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(80, 18));
            jTextArea4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(280, 60));
            jTextArea4.setText("jTextArea4");
            jTextArea4.setLineWrap(true);
            jTextArea5.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(80, 18));
            jTextArea5.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(280, 60));
            jTextArea5.setText("jTextArea5");
            jTextArea5.setLineWrap(true);
            jTextArea6.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(80, 18));
            jTextArea6.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(280, 60));
            jTextArea6.setText("jTextArea6");
            jTextArea6.setLineWrap(true);

            jpScope.setToolTipText("");
            jLabel7.setText("Risk :");
            jTextArea7.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(280, 60));
            jTextArea7.setText("jTextArea7");
            jTextArea7.setLineWrap(true);
            jpRisk.setLayout(borderLayout10);
            jpRisk.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(280, 60));
            jScrollPane6.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(284, 44));
            jScrollPane16.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(284, 44));
            jScrollPane5.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(284, 44));
            jScrollPane7.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(284, 44));
            jScrollPane14.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(284, 44));
            jScrollPane12.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(284, 44));
            jScrollPane10.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(284, 44));
            jScrollPane3.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.
                                                    VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
            jScrollPane9.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.
                                                    VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
            jScrollPane11.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.
                                                     VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
            jScrollPane13.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.
                                                     VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
            jScrollPane8.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.
                                                    VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
            jScrollPane4.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.
                                                    VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
            jScrollPane15.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.
                                                     VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
            jScrollPane1.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.
                                                    VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
            jMenuBar1.add(jMenuFile);
            jMenuFile.add(jMenuFileExit);
            jMenuBar1.add(jMenuHelp);
            jMenuHelp.add(jMenuHelpAbout);
            setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);
            jButton1.setIcon(image1);
            jButton1.setToolTipText("Open File");
            jButton2.setIcon(image2);
            jButton2.setToolTipText("Close File");
            jButton3.setIcon(image3);
            jButton3.setToolTipText("Help");
            jToolBar.add(jButton1);
            jToolBar.add(jButton2);
            jToolBar.add(jButton3);
            contentPane.add(statusBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            contentPane.add(jSplitPane1, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
            jSplitPane1.add(jPanel1, JSplitPane.LEFT);
            jSplitPane1.add(jPanel2, JSplitPane.RIGHT);
            jToolBar1.add(jtProjectList);
            jPanel1.add(jToolBar1, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
            jPanel1.add(jToolBar2, java.awt.BorderLayout.NORTH);
            jToolBar2.add(jbAdd);
            jToolBar2.add(jbRemove);
            jPanel2.add(jToolBar3, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
            jToolBar3.add(jScrollPane3);
            jScrollPane3.getViewport().add(jpCore);
            jpScope.add(jScrollPane1, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

            jScrollPane1.getViewport().add(jTextArea2);

            jScrollPane16.getViewport().add(jTable1);
            jScrollPane14.getViewport().add(jTable5);
            jScrollPane12.getViewport().add(jTable6);
            jScrollPane10.getViewport().add(jTable7);
            jScrollPane8.getViewport().add(jTextArea4);
            jScrollPane6.getViewport().add(jTable2);
            jScrollPane5.getViewport().add(jTable3);
            jScrollPane4.getViewport().add(jTextArea3);

            contentPane.add(jToolBar, java.awt.BorderLayout.NORTH);
            jpDeliverable.add(jScrollPane4, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
            jpDeliverable.add(jScrollPane5, java.awt.BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            jpDeliverable.add(jLabel3, java.awt.BorderLayout.NORTH);
            jpScope.add(jScrollPane6, java.awt.BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            jpScope.add(jLabel2, java.awt.BorderLayout.NORTH);
            jScrollPane7.getViewport().add(jTable4);
            jpAcceptance.add(jLabel6, java.awt.BorderLayout.NORTH);
            jScrollPane9.getViewport().add(jTextArea7);
            jpRisk.add(jScrollPane10, java.awt.BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            jpRisk.add(jScrollPane9, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
            jpRisk.add(jLabel7, java.awt.BorderLayout.NORTH);
            jScrollPane11.getViewport().add(jTextArea6);
            jpAssumption.add(jLabel4, java.awt.BorderLayout.NORTH);
            jpAssumption.add(jScrollPane12, java.awt.BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            jpAssumption.add(jScrollPane11, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
            jScrollPane13.getViewport().add(jTextArea5);
            jpConstraints.add(jLabel5, java.awt.BorderLayout.NORTH);
            jpConstraints.add(jScrollPane14, java.awt.BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            jpConstraints.add(jScrollPane13, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
            jScrollPane15.getViewport().add(jTextArea1);
            jpExclusion.add(jLabel1, java.awt.BorderLayout.NORTH);
            jpExclusion.add(jScrollPane16, java.awt.BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            jpExclusion.add(jScrollPane15, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

            jpAcceptance.add(jScrollPane8, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
            jpAcceptance.add(jScrollPane7, java.awt.BorderLayout.SOUTH);


            jpCore.add(jpScope, 0);
            jpCore.add(jpExclusion, 1);
            jpCore.add(jpDeliverable, 2);
            jpCore.add(jpAcceptance, 3);
            jpCore.add(jpConstraints, 4);
            jpCore.add(jpAssumption, 5);
            jpCore.add(jpRisk, 6);
            jSplitPane1.setDividerLocation(230);
        }

        /**
         * File | Exit action performed.
         *
         * @param actionEvent ActionEvent
         */
        void jMenuFileExit_actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            System.exit(0);
        }

        /**
         * Help | About action performed.
         *
         * @param actionEvent ActionEvent
         */
        void jMenuHelpAbout_actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            Frame1_AboutBox dlg = new Frame1_AboutBox(this);
            Dimension dlgSize = dlg.getPreferredSize();
            Dimension frmSize = getSize();
            Point loc = getLocation();
            dlg.setLocation((frmSize.width - dlgSize.width) / 2 + loc.x,
                            (frmSize.height - dlgSize.height) / 2 + loc.y);
            dlg.setModal(true);
            dlg.pack();
            dlg.setVisible(true);
        }

        public void jbRemove_actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            jtProjectList.removeCurrentNode();
        }

        public void jbAdd_actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            String response = "";
            while(response.trim().equals("")){
                response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this,
                        "Please enter name of node?",
                        "Enter your name",
                        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                //System.out.println(response);
                if( response != null && response.trim().equals(""))
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Please enter valid name",
                                                  "Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
            jtProjectList.addObject(response);

        }
    }


    class Frame1_jbAdd_actionAdapter implements ActionListener {
        private Frame1 adaptee;
        Frame1_jbAdd_actionAdapter(Frame1 adaptee) {
            this.adaptee = adaptee;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            adaptee.jbAdd_actionPerformed(actionEvent);
        }
    }


    class Frame1_jbRemove_actionAdapter implements ActionListener {
        private Frame1 adaptee;
        Frame1_jbRemove_actionAdapter(Frame1 adaptee) {
            this.adaptee = adaptee;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            adaptee.jbRemove_actionPerformed(actionEvent);
        }
    }


    class Frame1_jMenuFileExit_ActionAdapter implements ActionListener {
        Frame1 adaptee;

        Frame1_jMenuFileExit_ActionAdapter(Frame1 adaptee) {
            this.adaptee = adaptee;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            adaptee.jMenuFileExit_actionPerformed(actionEvent);
        }
    }


    class Frame1_jMenuHelpAbout_ActionAdapter implements ActionListener {
        Frame1 adaptee;

        Frame1_jMenuHelpAbout_ActionAdapter(Frame1 adaptee) {
            this.adaptee = adaptee;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            adaptee.jMenuHelpAbout_actionPerformed(actionEvent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: There's at least 16 `JScollPane`s in there. It would probably be easier to debug if you reproduce on a (much) shorter example, or at least tell use which one of the panes is not working as you expect.

Comment: See [sscce](http://sscce.org/) for tips on trimming your example.

Comment: I upload all of the code because it easy for u to run it, u can track problem for these Jscrollpane  : jScrollPane1
,jScrollPane16
jScrollPane4

Comment: No it's not. It's a large chunk of code and imports stuff from visibly thrid-party code (`import com.borland.jbcl.layout.*;`). You might find someone to look into it if you provide stuff including `main()` and without dependencies (or if you detail where/how to get those deps.)

Comment: remove that include, it is for before...

Comment: it is just for my layout

Comment: would u just check the style for me?it is very simple problem, but I dont know why I cant find it :((

Comment: Also `DynamicTree`, `VerticalFlowLayout` and `Frame1_AboutBox` are undefined symbols. If you want anybody to test anything, then you at least need to supply all symbols.

Comment: remove them :( please just looking a solution for those jscrollepain that I mention in above

Comment: It is NOT up to us to "remove them". It is up to you to post reasonable code that is easy to read and understand. That is why you have been given the link on posting a SSCCE. We can't just look at scrollpanes 1, 4, 16, because all the code works together. So we need to understand the entire program to understand how they work together.

Comment: Thanks yo us so much, I will solve my problem by myself later I will share my experience with you guys

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I solved my problem by small review on my codes:

I just remove this line:

```
jTextArea1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(280, 60));
```

Do not forget, if you set size (any size) for your Jtextarea scrollpane will not appear on screen for you :)

job done, enjoy it....

Comment: The preferred size of a `JTextArea` can be set by using appropriate arguments in the constructor.  It is neither necessary nor desirable to make random guesses about the size a component should be, when there are better ways to specify the size.

Comment: I guess u didnt understand my question?!!if you set size for your jtextArea and than add it to jscrollpane , your JSCrollepane not working!

Comment: Sorry but that's just wrong. The problem is not due to setting the size, but the fact that the JScrollPane is not properly linked to the JTextArea.  My answer still stands.

Comment: I know my error was funny and also I asked this question because I also sup prizing by receiving this error as well....anyway my problem solved now

Answer (score 4):

I believe the reason your code is so messy is because it was generated automatically by some GUI builder.  With the large number of components and the complexity of your interface, you might want to write it manually.  There must be some kind of pattern here that you can exploit to reduce the amount of code and make it easier to understand and maintain.

With that aside, I think the problem could be down to the way the components are 'added' to the `JScrollPane`s.  You used

`jScrollPaneX.getViewport().add(comp);`

which is not the usual way of assigning a view to a scroll pane.  The standard ways are by choosing the view component at construct time such as by calling

`jScrollPanex = new JScrollPane(comp)`

or if you need to set it later, call

`jScrollPaneX.setViewportView(comp)`.

*(Internally, this calls `getViewport().setView(view)` which is similar, but not the same as the way you were doing it.)*